# error: cannot find symbol variable listView

Tags: java, android, listview, navigation-drawer

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item+"선택",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

After creating navigationDrawer, OnItemClick events were added to ListView.
But it doesn't work.

```
Error:(74, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable listView
```

The above error occurs. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: post the whole class

Comment: @Nigam Patro  I edit post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says listView is not defined in your code, so there is no reference to this object. try to define it in this class or in the super class